# reverse next/prev page order

Tags: navigation

I think the way wordpress display previous and next posts is basically non sense, with next posts on the left side, and older posts on the right side.

I am using the code

```
<?php posts_nav_link() ?>
```

is there a way to reverse such order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because it is, by default, done as 'previous page' on the left, and 'next page' on the right. Posts appear in reverse chronological order, with the latest post first, so 'next  page' means going back in time. So in terms of pages it makes sense, in terms of chronology it doesn't.

Anyway... this should work:

```
<div class="navigation">
   <div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries','') ?></div>
   <div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link

Note: since weblog posts are traditionally listed in reverse chronological order (with most recent posts at the top), there is some ambiguity in the definition of "next page". WordPress defines "next page" as the "next page toward the past". In WordPress 1.5, the default Kubrick theme addresses this ambiguity by labeling the "next page" link as "previous entries". See Example: Kubrick Theme Format.

You can use next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() separately  and place where ever you want in your template.....

Answer (score 0):

The function...

```
posts_nav_link( $separator, $prev_label, $next_label );
```

...calls...

```
get_posts_nav_link()
```

...where the defaults for the previous function come from. If then the `query_var`

```
$query->max_num_pages // must be greater than one to trigger
```

...is set, the functions...

```
get_previous_posts_link()
get_next_posts_link()
```

get called. If then...

```
$query->paged // must be set lower than 2 
$query->max_num_pages // or equal to $paged
```

...meets, the function will add a separator between both links.

Answer (score 0):

Another WordPress way to display navigation (pagination):

```
<nav class="navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Search Navigation">
  <div class="nav-links">
    <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This will display the pagination having Next to the right side and Back to the left side. It will also display the pagination numbers. You can hide these with CSS if necessary.